# Is 9000 DOM elements big?

Tags: javascript, dom

I just want a perspective about this. I am building a app with force layout graph and tables. Using

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").length
```

I can see my DOM is about 9000 nodes. With this number, the app slowed down. Is this number of DOM normal in other applications you guys normally build?

Comment: ~I don't think so.~ This page itself, which contains this question, has over 720 elements. --- __OVER 9000!__

Comment: Depends on your specific application. Factor in what you have on the page, CSS, Javascipt, Event Listeners.

Comment: I agree with @evolutionxbox, I just checked on facebook and that only has ~2000

Comment: Use proper profiling on your page. Aren't there any suspicious intervals running? Aren't you tracking mouse cursor? Do you modify DOM using `innerHTML` setter? These are just few of many possible issues.

Comment: It depends all on performance. Users don't care about the number of DOM elements, they care if the app runs well *on their device.* When you test your app, make sure to not only include modern smartphones, but also the most recent few generations, if possible. If you notice any latency on your development machine, it will definitely be noticed on a lower powered mobile device

Answer (score 1):

Not that unusual for tables, especially if there are widgets in the table cells. Remember: Nodes ≃ rows ✕ columns ✕  (nodes per cell). The main thing for performance is a consequent asynchronuous approach, decoupling content updates from screen events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.
It is recommended to avoid having too many nodes at a time. You need to have your partial loading mechanism. You can also set the display to none for the elements that are not in view.

Comment: That may well be detrimental, because deciding which elements are in view means querying the layout engine, and that will trigger a complete re-layout. Things will be faster nowadays, but 4 years back, I was estimating 1 second computing time for 10.000 nodes.